# Changing the memory address of an object created with a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I'm a python newbie currently creating a simple game where a player object moves around a maze with several puddles. The classes I've set for the game cells are: Start(), Wall(), Blank(), Water() and Finish(). The game's board is created by taking in a text file with the maze, a simple e.g. being

```
-S----
-  W -
-W   -
---F--
```

(where S is Start(), W is Water(), - are the Walls() and F is Finish()) and then converting each string into their respective class objects. My current technique is converting the gameboard into a list of lists then iterating through it by using a dictionary to identify the string and create corresponding class objects then swap out the string with the new object.

```
types_of_cells = {
    "S": Start(),
    "F": Finish(),
    " ": Blank(),
    "-": Wall()
    "W": Water()
}

i = 0
cell_list = []

while i < len(lines):
    cell_list.append(list(lines[i].strip()))
    j = 0
    while j < len(cell_list[i]):
        if cell_list[i][j] in types_of_cells:
            cell = types_of_cells[cell_list[i][j]]
            cell_list[i][j] = cell
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

After I splash through a Water() puddle, the cell is converted into a Blank() cell. However, my issue is that all of the memory addresses of cells of one particular class are the same. That is, all Water() cells will be  for the entire board. As such, I can't remove any single water cell without removing all existing water cells on the gameboard.

By essentially doing cell = Water() then cell_list[i][j] = cell in a loop, I assumed that I was creating new Water() cells with differing memory addresses but apparently not...? So I was wondering whether the class objects placed into the dictionary all have the same addresses? Or something like that.

Comment: You want to do `cell_list[i][j] = Water()`, which creates a new `Water` object every time you execute it. Otherwise, you'll be referencing the same object.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.